# How to get missing dll file error callback in nsh code in run time (NSIS)

Tags: nsis

I am creating an installer for my software using NSIS. My software is dependent on Microsoft c++ redistribution software. So while installing my software if user system has some .dll files missing/corrupted then the installer shows error.

I want that whenever such error comes NSIS script gets a error callback I start the c++ redistribution software installation first.

So how  to achieve this?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: The installer does not technically display this error, it is the Windows loader. You also forgot to post your code showing how you execute.

Answer (score 0):

Ship this executable. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Install with

```
ExecWait '"vc_redist.x86.exe"'
```

A clever way to not leave it lying around is:

```
InitPluginsDir  ; If you haven't already
SetOutPath $PLUGINSDIR
File vc_redist.x86.exe
ExecWait '"vc_redist.x86.exe"'
SetOutPath $INSTDIR
```

It creates its own installation entry in Control Panel, so you do nothing on uninstall.

(If your program is 64 bit you need the 64 bit version and will find the pluginsdir method much less error prone in that case.)